# How to create this JSON structure in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
"fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "hello!"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "hello!"
          ]
        }
      }
]
```

How can I create an object such as this in PHP? I understand that [] = array and {} object, but its unclear to me how to put an array inside an object and to do it in a proper way as to be send as JSON

Comment: In PHP, array ~ associative-array (with only integer keys). So, search for "tutorial create PHP array". It will show multiple methods, to create the correct 'kind' of array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php note "Example #1 A simple array" (aka 'create object') and "Example #4 Indexed arrays without key" (aka 'create array') sections, which will answer the above. The 5.4 syntax also works in the latter case: `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: in PHP its called an associative array, json_encode will take care of the rest: https://3v4l.org/alPGr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the official documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Normally, we transform an array into a json structure.

Here's an example:

```
$array = ['a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => 4];
$json = json_encode($array);
```

It will return this json: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":4}

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick primer:

```
function jdump($thing) {
    printf("%s\n\n", json_encode($thing, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}

jdump(['foo', 'bar']);
jdump(['foo' => 'bar']);
jdump([['a' => 1],['b' => 2],['c' => 3]]);
```

Output:

```
[
    "foo",
    "bar"
]

{
    "foo": "bar"
}

[
    {
        "a": 1
    },
    {
        "b": 2
    },
    {
        "c": 3
    }
]
```